# ConnectionString not decrypted for Windows Service

Tags: c#, asp.net, windows, iis

I have a Windows service, that has 2 connection strings to connect to the database.

Recently, for enhanced security, I encrypted the connection strings using the **aspnet_regiis** tool. This provided the data in the encrypted form. But the connection strings are not retreived/found in the service while it is running.

The only connection string that is found is a connection to "SQL_Server_Express", which I haven't mentioned in the App.config.

The strange part is that I have used the same approach of encrypting\decrypting connectionstrings on a Web application and it works fine.

Any suggestions/help will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Side note - the Express connection should be the one called `LocalSqlServer`. It comes from `machine.config`.